# R parallel processing with Caret computation issues

Tags: r, parallel-processing, r-caret, rfe

Currently trying to reproduce an SVM recursive feature elimination algorithm using parallel processing, but ran into some issues with the parallelization backend.

When the RFE SVM algorithm runs successfully in parallel, this takes about 250 seconds. However, most of the time it never completes the computations and needs to be manually shut down after 30 minutes. When the latter happens, examination of the activity monitor shows that the cores are still running despite Rstudio having shut it down. These cores need to be terminated using `killall R` from the terminal.

Code snippet as found in the package `AppliedPredictiveModeling` is below, with redundant code removed.

```
library(AppliedPredictiveModeling)
data(AlzheimerDisease)

## The baseline set of predictors
bl <- c("Genotype", "age", "tau", "p_tau", "Ab_42", "male")

## The set of new assays
newAssays <- colnames(predictors)
newAssays <- newAssays[!(newAssays %in% c("Class", bl))]

## Decompose the genotype factor into binary dummy variables

predictors$E2 <- predictors$E3 <- predictors$E4 <- 0
predictors$E2[grepl("2", predictors$Genotype)] <- 1
predictors$E3[grepl("3", predictors$Genotype)] <- 1
predictors$E4[grepl("4", predictors$Genotype)] <- 1
genotype <-  predictors$Genotype

## Partition the data
library(caret)
set.seed(730)
split <- createDataPartition(diagnosis, p = .8, list = FALSE)

adData <- predictors
adData$Class <- diagnosis

training <- adData[ split, ]
testing  <- adData[-split, ]

predVars <- names(adData)[!(names(adData) %in% c("Class",  "Genotype"))]

## This summary function is used to evaluate the models.
fiveStats <- function(...) c(twoClassSummary(...), defaultSummary(...))

## We create the cross-validation files as a list to use with different 
## functions

set.seed(104)
index <- createMultiFolds(training$Class, times = 5)

## The candidate set of the number of predictors to evaluate
varSeq <- seq(1, length(predVars)-1, by = 2)

# Beginning parallelization 
library(doParallel)
cl <- makeCluster(7)
registerDoParallel(cl) 
getDoParWorkers() 

# Rfe and train control objects created
ctrl <- rfeControl(method = "repeatedcv", repeats = 5,
                   saveDetails = TRUE,
                   index = index,
                   returnResamp = "final")

fullCtrl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",
                         repeats = 5,
                         summaryFunction = fiveStats,
                         classProbs = TRUE,
                         index = index)


## Here, the caretFuncs list allows for a model to be tuned at each iteration 
## of feature seleciton.

ctrl$functions <- caretFuncs
ctrl$functions$summary <- fiveStats

## This options tells train() to run it's model tuning
## sequentially. Otherwise, there would be parallel processing at two
## levels, which is possible but requires W^2 workers. On our machine,
## it was more efficient to only run the RFE process in parallel. 

cvCtrl <- trainControl(method = "cv",
                       verboseIter = FALSE,
                       classProbs = TRUE,
                       allowParallel = FALSE)

set.seed(721)
svmRFE <- rfe(training[, predVars],
              training$Class,
              sizes = varSeq,
              rfeControl = ctrl,
              metric = "ROC",
              ## Now arguments to train() are used.
              method = "svmRadial",
              tuneLength = 12,
              preProc = c("center", "scale"),
              trControl = cvCtrl)
```

This is not the only model which has caused me issues. Sometimes the random forest with RFE also causes the same problem. The original code uses the package `doMQ`, however, examination of the activity monitor shows multiple `rsession` which serve as the parallelization, and which I'm guessing run using the GUI as shutting this down when computations do not stop requires aborting the entire R communication and restarting the session, rather than simply abandoning the computations. The former of course has the unfortunate consequence of wiping my environment clean.

I'm using a MacBook Pro mid-2013 with 8 cores.

Any idea what may be causing this issue? Is there a way to fix it, and if so, what? Is there a way to ensure that the parallelization runs without the GUI without running scripts from the terminal (I'd like to have control over which models are executed and when).

Edit: It seems that after quitting the failed execution, R fails on all subsequent tasks which are parallelized through Caret, even those which ran before. This implies the clusters are no longer operational.